# How can i set this path in java?

Tags: batch-file, path, command, escaping, processbuilder

I want to execute a batch command via java.
how can I do that ?
"c:\windows\system32\net use s: \192.168.1.160"\100 Gelem 1" /user:xxx xxx"
this one actually works on windows command prompt

the code I tries witout success is :

```
String[] cmd = { "c:\\windows\\system32\\net","use s: \\\\192.168.1.160\"\\100 Gelem 1     \" /user:100 100"};

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
p.waitFor();
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: Spaces and quotes? "c:\\windows\\system32\\net","use s: \"\\\\192.168.1.160\\100 Gelem 1\" /user:100 100"

Comment: Try splitting up each argument into separate elements in the array.  String[] cmd = { "c:\\windows\\system32\\net","use", "s:", "\\\\192.168.1.160\\100 Gelem 1     ", "/user:100", "100"};

Comment: still not working :( the proper way Dos runs it , is like so :  c:\windows\system32\net.exe use s: "\\192.168.1.160\100 Gelem 1"
 /user:100 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked it out !!!

```
cmd1 = "c:\\windows\\system32\\net.exe " + "use" + " s:" +
                   " \"\\\\192.168.1.160\\100 Gelem 1\"" + " /user:100" + " 100";
String[] cmd = {cmd1};
```